# TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I made a Todo app with Angularjs and Ionic.
I want to save to localStorage some fields, but when i click save I get this error.

My code is:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ionic'])
    .controller('myAppCtrl', function($scope){

        $scope.uuid = function(){
            return Math.floor(( 1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
                .toString(16)
                .substring(1);
        };

        $scope.todo = {};
        $scope.todos = {};

        //Check The Localstorage If the Todos exists
        var todos = localStorage.getItem('todos');

        if(todos !== undefined){
            $scope.todos = JSON.parse(todos);
        }

        $scope.addTodo = function($event){
            activate_page("#create_edit");
        };

        $scope.goBack = function($event){
            activate_page("#mainpage");
        };

        $scope.saveTodo = function($event){

            $scope.todo.id = $scope.uuid();
            $scope.todos.push($scope.todo);
            $scope.todo = {};
            localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify($scope.todos)); //Save 
            activate_page("#mainpage");            
        };
    });
```

Can you help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare and initialize the variable  $scope.todos like below since you are pushing to an **object** not **array**

```
 $scope.todos = [];
```

Comment: in angular 2 u can use  todos: any = [];

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to `push` to a JSON object, not an array, which is defined like so:

`$scope.todos = [];`

Comment: what is different from my answer?

Comment: Was posting at the same time, you were just a bit faster.